# Responsive design using Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a requirement to change a static site to responsive. To make it responsive, they have asked to make use of Bootstrap 3. They do not want the look and feel of the desktop view to change. It should look the same as now. But the site must render properly in mobile and tablets. May I target the mobile and tablet views alone using visibility classes in Bootstrap 3 without altering the current code for desktop. Is it feasible?

Comment: can you share what you have done..??

Comment: surely you can, media quires can Handel all stuff for mobile. i have done this couple of times

Comment: You can do it but it means that you have to render everything twice then hide the parts that are not designed for the user's display. Therefore this increases the size of content user have to download in order to see your site. I would try to bring everything in a single responsive design but if it is not possible for you do it like you described.